# time complexity of a recursive function of a depth first walk of a graph

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, python-3.6

I am a starter in learning recursive function and time-complexity. 
I have this recursive function:

```
def walk(g, visited_Set):
    if g is None or g in visited: return
    visited_Set.add(g) ### mark as visited
    print(g.value) ### process before visiting outgoing edges
    for node in g.edges:
        walk(node, visited_Set) ### walk all outgoing edge targets
```

In the worst case, if every node is connected to the other nodes. 
Would this be a n^n time complexity or n^2 time complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming set lookup and insertion are `O(1)`, the graph traversal will have `O(n + e)` where `n` is the number of nodes and `e` is the number of edges.

So if you consider a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) to be your worst case, it has `n(n-1)/2` edges which would make a time complexity of `O(n + n(n-1)/2)` - `O(n²)`.

Answer (score 0):

If worst case is every node hits every other node than it should be n^2.

for every n (n times), we will hit every again n (n times). So we'll hit n, n times.

Imagine if you have an array of 5 items:

[A, B, C, D, E]

if each index is compared to every other index we have :

A compared to A, B , C, D, E (5 times)

B compared to A, B, C.... (5 times)

...

E compared to A, B, C, D, E (5 times)

if n = 5 than we have n^2 :D